# Automatic application skeletal code generation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, yii

I am developing in Yii 1.0 for four years. For me its the World's fastest web app development framework.

I create basic application skeleton with just a command. This app skeleton contains authentication and basic pages. I always take this skeleton as application base and customize.

Now, I just setup Laravel. It worked but with a single page. Can I generate code in Laravel like I do in Yii??

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel provides a quick way to scaffold all of the routes and views you need for authentication using one simple command.For creating a boilerplate/basic pages you can use the artisan tool to generate a beautiful bootstrap welcome view and controllers.

**What you need to do?**

- Create a database
- Configure the database in `.env` file just by adding your DB name ( for more [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#introduction) )
- Make sure to run php artisan migrate, it will migrate the tables to database
- Now fun part just write `php artisan make:auth` in your console.
- Now visit your localhost/yourapp/ and you will see a beautiful bootstrap view dancing over there along with registration form.

Comment: @Martha James Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Craft your laravel application faster and easier by [The scaffold-interface](https://github.com/amranidev/scaffold-interface)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate files for authorization and some starting login/register boilerplate, you should run `php artisan make:auth` in your console. There are several options available for making starting boilerplate together with flags for each command.

Just type `php artisan` in your console and see the options it provides under `make`. It should be pretty straightforward

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try [Vemto](https://vemto.app) which is a Laravel Studio and Code Generator with a GUI that can generate complete applications, from the Models to the CRUD, including the tests.